# ControlTemplate Bind to ToolTip property from button

Tags: c#, jquery

I want to add some text next to my button, but I want to use the tooltip for this text or better yet another tag I can add within the controls properties.

Then I want to reference this tag within my ControlTemplate so it will add the text next to my button, here is my button XAML:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MainMenuButton}" ToolTip="Home" Content="" />
```

And here is my Style:

```
<Style x:Key="MainMenuButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="27" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#545863" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid x:Name="grid">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0" x:Name="border" 
                                    CornerRadius="40" 
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                  TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" />
                            </Border>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContex.ToolTip}" 
                                           FontSize="16"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#757b8d" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#29a1d5" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

The code I have there now doesn't work: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContex.ToolTip}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woopps, found the solution. Was far too simple and I expected it be more complicated.

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" FontSize="16"/>
```